# Как правильно: шевелИтся или шевЕлится?

Tags: орфоэпия

Если правильны оба варианта, то какой из них более современный и используется чаще?

Почему вообще ударение в этом глаголе смещается на основу (шевелИть - шевЕлит)? Это только частный случай или есть  еще такие примеры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сегодня в словарях даются два варианта: шевелИтся или шевЕлится. Причем  в качестве основного варианта отмечается ударение на третьем слоге: шевелИшь, шевелИт, шевелЯт, шевелИм, шевелИте.

См.например: Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова. Словарь ударений русского языка.

Что касается смещения ударения, то не всегда можно объяснить причины. Это зачастую обусловлено множеством факторов.